# Adapter cannot be applied to a recycleview search

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to call the SeachAdapter to my Activity but I can't get the list value because it displays can not be applied

Here is my activity code with same error

```
adapter = new SearchAdapter(this.mOwnerDao.getOwner());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private void startSearch(String text) {
    adapter = new SearchAdapter(this.mOwnerDao.getOwnerByName(text));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

My SearchAdapter

```
public class SearchAdapter  extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchViewHolder>{
private Context context;
private List<Owner> owners;

public SearchAdapter(Context context, List<Owner> owners)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.owners = owners;
}


@Override
public SearchViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_item,parent,false);
    return new SearchViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SearchViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.name.setText(owners.get(position).getName());
    holder.phoneNumber.setText(owners.get(position).getPhoneNumber());
    holder.address.setText(owners.get(position).getAddress());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return owners.size();
}
}
```

Comment: You have to pass context as first parameter and list as second parameter , separated by comma

Comment: It worked.Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: -

```
private void startSearch(String text) {
    adapter = new SearchAdapter(this, this.mOwnerDao.getOwnerByName(text));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing Layout Manager to your recyclerview. Post more code. Sorry i don't have reputation to comment so posting as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Pass `this` at first parameter in `SearchAdapter` function every time when you call this function

```
new SearchAdapter(this,this.mOwnerDao.getOwner());
```